# Check if PanResponder value exceeds View width

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am creating a `PanResponder` in my `componentWillMount` method

```
componentWillMount() {
  this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({
    onMoveShouldSetResponderCapture: () => true,

    onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: () => true,

    onPanResponderMove: Animated.event([null, { dx: this.state.pan }]),

    onPanResponderRelease: (e, {vx, vy}) => {
      // here I want to check if pan exceeded the width of the View container
    ]
  });
}
```

The problem is that I don't know how to detect the size of the width.

In my `render` method, I could do something like this

```
return (
  <View onLayout={event => this.setState({ viewWidth: event.nativeEvent.layout.width })}>
    ..
  </View>
);
```

but I cannot access `this.state.viewWidth` in `componentWillMount`, since the method is only rendered before the view is mounted.

I am trying to make a slider that goes from left to right, so I need a minimum and maximum X value, where the minimum X value is simply 0.

So when defining the position, I am using

```
// Current position
const left = pan.interpolate({
  inputRange: [0, viewWidth],
  outputRange: [0, viewWidth],
  extrapolate: 'clamp'
});

return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <View style={{ position: 'absolute', left, width: 100, height: 100 , backgroundColor: 'red' }} />
  </View>
);
```

but maybe it could be done differently with `0` and `1` as values, so I in `onPanResponderRelease` could simply check if the `pan` value exceeds `1`?

Comment: Have you tried using `componentDidMount` or `componentDidUpdate`?

Answer (score 0):

I would initialize the `viewWidth` state to `false`, and use `componentDidUpdate` to initialize the `PanResponder`. Just check that `state.viewWidth` is set and that it wasn't in `prevState.viewWidth`:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (this.state.viewWidth && prevState.viewWidth === false) {
        this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({
        onMoveShouldSetResponderCapture: () => true,

        onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: () => true,

        onPanResponderMove: Animated.event([null, { dx: this.state.pan }]),

        onPanResponderRelease: (e, {vx, vy}) => {
          // here I want to check if pan exceeded the width of the View container
        });
    }
}
```